# flutter Navigation page Radius

Tags: flutter

How to make the page curved and consistent with the screen during page redirection?
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VU9so.jpg)

```
return SlideTransition(
            position: offsetAnimation,
            child: ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: animation.value == 1
                  ? BorderRadius.zero
                  : const BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(25)),
              child: child,
            ),
          );
```

The method I am currently using is not very good。

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to know the border radius of the device, correct?

There's a package you can use called [device_corner_radius](https://github.com/rehmatsg/device_corner_radius). On Android, it only works with API 31 and above. Also be aware that this *could* lead to your app getting rejected on the iOS App Store as the package uses a private API to get the corner radius which Apple is not a fan of. I don't know how true that is though.

You can use it like so:

```dart
final BorderRadius radius = await DeviceCornerRadus.getCornerRadius();
```